# @Autowired member not initialized in a Junit 5 test written in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, autowired, junit5

I can't get an @Autowired member to be initialized in a JUnit 5 test.  Here is the test:

```
import org.amshove.kluent.`should be equal to`
import org.junit.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

@SpringBootTest
class SnackQueryResolverTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    class SnackQueryResolverTestConfig {
        @Bean
        fun snackQueryResolverFactory() = SnackQueryResolver()
    }

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var snackQueryResolver: SnackQueryResolver

    @Test
    fun `snacks`() {
        val snacks = snackQueryResolver.snacks()
        snacks.size `should be equal to` 5
    }
}
```

When the test is run I receive the error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property snackQueryResolver has not been initialized
```

If I eliminate the @Autowired and instantiate the bean during construction, the test runs fine:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SnackQueryResolverTest {
    private val snackQueryResolver: SnackQueryResolver = SnackQueryResolver()

    @Test
    fun `snacks`() {
        val snacks = snackQueryResolver.snacks()
        snacks.size `should be equal to` 5
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

Turns out a small error was causing the issue - careless with IDE code completion.  For @Test, I was importing:

```
import org.junit.Test
```

instead, this needs to be used for JUnit 5 tests:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd made the same mistake and was pulling my hair out!